# Access field of a record where field name is specified dynamically

Tags: purescript

In purescript, let’s say I have a type.

```
newtype Person = Person {name::String, age::Int}
```

I want to create a function which takes this record and a string specifying the field name, e.g. name, and returns the value of that field.

My use case is that I will have a record and I want concatanation of some of those fields. I want to pass an array of strings which will be the field names, and then using fold get it done in one line. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Does it have to be strings? Or can you hard-code functions, e.g. `\p -> p.name`?

Comment: I got suggested the same and I think that's the next best solution. But is there a way to achieve what I asked for?

Comment: Have a look at a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758148/purescript-types-for-buildquerystring-function

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

With [`get`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record/2.0.0/docs/Record#v:get) from [`purescript-record`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record/2.0.0): `get (SProxy ∷ SProxy "x") { x: 6 }` reduces to `6`. Note that this requires the string to be known statically, as well as the record type.

If you wish to dynamically index a JavaScript object, you can use [`readProp`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign/5.0.0/docs/Foreign.Index#v:readProp) from [`purescript-foreign`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign/5.0.0). However, the Foreign library cannot safely operate on PureScript records.

An option to dynamically index a PureScript record is to simply do case analysis on the string.

```
getProp ∷ ∀ a b r. String → { x ∷ a, y ∷ b | r } → Maybe (Either a b)
getProp "x" rec = Just (Left rec.x)
getProp "y" rec = Just (Right rec.y)
getProp _ _ = Nothing
```